# Enforcing an interface on a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark-dataset

I'm new to Spark and was wondering if the following is possible.

I have 2 `Datasets`, and they both have fields `EventTime` and `UserId`. However, they differ in all other columns.

I want to write a function that takes in these `Datasets` and spits out the last time I saw each user.

This is easy enough, because we can select the row with the maximum time for each user (`groupby`)

Let's say I have a function `LastSeenTime(events: DataFrame): DataFrame { ... }`

My question is how would you organize the code, and potentially define a type/interface such that `LastSeenTime` can enforce that `events` has the `UserId` and `EventTime` columns it needs to do the processing.

Can Dataset Schema's conform to partial interfaces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make something like this:

```
sealed trait Event {
  def userId: String
  def eventTime: String
}

final case class UserEvent(userId: String, eventTime: String, otherField: String) extends Event

def lastTimeByUser[E <: Event, T](events: Dataset[E]): Dataset[T] = ???
```

## Edit

If you're using a `Dataframe`, you can *"cast"* it to a `Dataset[T]` using the `.as[T]` **method**.  *(Where `T` is the **case class** you want to use for represent your data - must have the same fields of your `Rows`)*.
Note, you will need a **implicit** `Encoder[T]` in the scope for that - the simplest way to provide it is `import spark.implicits._`, where `spark` is an instance of `SparkSession`.

Comment: This looks like just what I need. Can you explain what the syntax `Dataset[Event]` does? Is it some sort of templating ?

Comment: @VishaalKalwani Yes, is just a normal [Scala generics](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html). It means is the method accepts as input a **Dataset** of **Events**.

Comment: To elaborate on this. `Dataframe` is a type alias for `Dataset[Row]` and `Row` is just a glorified `Map[String, Any]` and `Dataframe` basically just has a bunch of additional syntax tacked to it.

Personally I'd recomment `def lastTimeByUser[T <: Event](events: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T] = ???` because that will not lose you type information when calling the function with a `Dataset[UserEvent]`

Comment: @DominicEgger, yes you're right - I have updated the answer. I also provided information about transforming a `Dataframe` into a `Dataset` for clarification. Please feel free to edit it if you believe you can be more consince than me.